# How to return a list from a list of elements that have a list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have an API and I have a list of diets that have a list of recipes inside them. It's a many to many relationship, I've been trying to get just the list of recipes from a specific diet, but  I can only get the whole list of diets including their list of recipes but I just want to get the list of recipes. This the actual code.

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Diet>> GetRecipesFromDiet([FromRoute] int DietId)
    {
        var diet = _context.Diets.AsQueryable();
        diet = diet.Include(d => d.Recipes).AsNoTracking();
        List<Diet> _return = await diet.ToListAsync();
        return _return;
    }
```

I've already tried to use where to only get the specific diet but it returns me an empty list so it's not an option. I even saw a solution here from someone that had the same problem ([Return list object with list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422703/return-list-object-with-list-object)) but I tried it and it gives an error. This was the code I tried.

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Diet>> GetRecipesFromDiet([FromRoute] int DietId)
    {
        var result = _context.Diets.Where(d => d.DietId == DietId).Select(d => new
        {
            Recipes = d.Recipes.Select(recipe => new
            {
                RecipeId = recipe.RecipeId,
                Name = recipe.Name,
                Description = recipe.Description,
                Preparation = recipe.Preparation,
                Ingredientes = recipe.Ingredients
            }).ToList(),
        });
        return (IEnumerable<Diet>)result;
    }
```

I had to add an explicit convertion because visual studio told me so, I also tried to change the type of the method to `Task<IEnumerable<Recipe>>` with no results either. The error it gives is this one.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NutricareApp.Entities.Diet]'. at NutricareApp.Web.Controllers.DietsController.GetRecipesFromDiet(Int32 DietId) in D:\Projects\C#\Server-Side-Software\NutricareApp.Web\Controllers\DietsController.cs:line 77 at lambda_method6(Closure , Object ) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) HEADERS ======= Accept: text/plain Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8 Connection: close Cookie: Webstorm-1c66ffc5=ab57cd81-dd6b-4581-b4ce-e7c3216efe1b; Webstorm-1c670386=5cdc986c-d091-40b5-aafa-eba19ed04173 Host: localhost:44394 Referer: https://localhost:44394/swagger/index.html User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36 sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91" sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 sec-fetch-site: same-origin sec-fetch-mode: cors sec-fetch-dest: empty

The answer also mentions to follow EF conventions and my code was like that so I just had to follow the last part but I got this error and I don't know what else to do. To be completely clear I just want the list of recipes from a specific diet, not the diet with the recipes just the recipes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some tries I got a solution

```
    [HttpGet("[action]/{DietId}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<RecipeModel>> GetRecipesFromDiet([FromRoute] int DietId)
    {
        var diets = await _context.Diets
                                .Include(d => d.Recipes)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.DietId == DietId);
        var recipes = diets.Recipes.ToList();
        return recipes.Select(c => new RecipeModel
        {
            RecipeId = c.RecipeId,
            NutritionistId = c.NutritionistId,
            Name = c.Name,
            Ingredients = c.Ingredients,
            Description = c.Description,
            Preparation = c.Preparation
        });
    }
```

I had to use a model to "print" the recipes and not create a loop (Just returning the list will lead to a "unable to cast object type", keep that in mind). Also, it didn't get any diet in the first try because I forgot to add the id to the route "[action]/{DietId}". Thanks for your help I hope if someone else face this problem this can help them.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the `Diet`s out of the EF query using `ToListAsync`.  Then grab the `Recipes` off them.

```
var diets = await _context.Diets
                          .Include(d => d.Recipes)
                          .Where(d => d.DietId == DietId)
                          .ToListAsync();
    
return diets.Select(x => x.Recipes).ToList();
```

Comment: It still gives the error of "unable to cast object type", even with an explicit convertion

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to select off of your joining table (obviously I don't know what you've called it, so change Diets_To_Recipes as needed):

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Recipe>> GetRecipesFromDiet([FromRoute] int DietId)
{
    return _context.Diets_To_Recipes.Where(x => x.DietId == DietId)
           .Select(x => x.Recipe);
}
```

Comment: Yeah about that, I actually don't have a joining table since it's not necessary to create one if the table is only gonna have the pks (EF creates it for you so you don't have to create them), it's mentioned on the link I gave

Comment: @DarkMage I don't know if EF can translate this to SQL but you could try `Recipes.Where(x => x.Diets.Any(y => y.Id == DietId))`

Comment: I've already solved the problem, my answer is bellow, thanks for the help.